# Resolving an Object by Type and Registration issue in MVC and Strategy pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, strategy-pattern

> I opened ticket last week ticket is
>   [Asp.Net MVC and Strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492226/asp-net-mvc-and-strategy-pattern/30495713?noredirect=1#comment49069728_30495713)
>   in that ticket Brendan solution worked but once i implemented one more class and implemented IAuthStrategy on that class and registered in unity container only last register class code is executing and i want to execute each on certain condition, my new class code is

```
public class WindowsMechanism : IAuthStrategy
{

    private IInstitutionRepository _institutionRepository;

    public UserNamePasswordMechanism(IInstitutionRepository institutionRepository)
    {
        this._institutionRepository = institutionRepository;
    }

    public OperationResponse<AuthenticationMechanismDTO> GetAuthenticationMechanism(string userName)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> and unity registration is this which is in unityConfig.cs

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthStrategy, UserNamePasswordMechanism>();
container.RegisterType<IAuthStrategy, WindowsAuthMechanism>();
```

> i am not able to fix this issue any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrote IAuthStrategy. You can add name for resolved

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthStrategy, UserNamePasswordMechanism>("UserNamePasswordMechanish");
container.RegisterType<IAuthStrategy, WindowsAuthMechanism>("WindowsAuthMechanism");
```

And them

```
IAuthStrategytheDataService = container.Resolve<IAuthStrategy>("UserNamePasswordMechanish");
IAuthStrategytheLoggingService = container.Resolve<IAuthStrategy>("WindowsAuthMechanism");
```

You can check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx), if you want